# Dropdown search Issue

Tags: angular

When I search in dropdown it shows no match found if no results...but when I focused out "no match found" added as an option. how can I resolve this?

I added my code and screenshot here.

```
    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" class="full-width transparent-form">
        <input matInput focused="'true'" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchKey" autocomplete="off" (keydown)="inputKeyPressDown($event)" (keyup)="searchReportTo($event)"
            placeholder="Search Report To">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-option class="pointer-none" *ngIf="noResults">No match found</mat-option>
```

Comment: here no need to use mat-option please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you have created error message with the **mat-option** component. That's why `No Match found` as an option added in your options array.  You can use simple div to create the error message like below.

```
<div class="pointer-none" *ngIf="noResults">No match found</div>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: can create stackblitz for this so that I will solve your problem more easily

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
    <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="state.flag" height="25">
    <span>{{state.name}}</span> |
    <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngif="filteredStates.length == 0">No match found
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```